# Rails joins where query on association model and parent model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join

I have models `AutoCompany` and `AutoCompanyBranches`.

I want to fetch auto companies with specific `ID` and specific branches countries. My query

```
AutoCompany.joins(:auto_company_branches).where("auto_company_branches.country_id =? and id=?",country_id,id)
```

It gives an error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'auto_company_branches WHERE (`auto_companies`.deleted_at IS NULL) AND (auto_comp' at line 1: SELECT `auto_companies`.`id` AS t0_r0, `auto_companies`.`name` AS t0_r1, `auto_companies`.`phone` AS t0_r2, `auto_companies`.`country_id` AS t0_r3, `auto_companies`.`city_id` AS t0_r4, `auto_companies`.`physical_address` AS t0_r5, `auto_companies`.`email` AS t0_r6, `auto_companies`.`website` AS t0_r7, `auto_companies`.`lat` AS t0_r8, `auto_companies`.`lng` AS t0_r9, `auto_companies`.`slug` AS t0_r10, `auto_companies`.`delta` AS t0_r11, `auto_companies`.`average_rating` AS t0_r12, `auto_companies`.`rating_count` AS t0_r13, `auto_companies`.`rating_sum` AS t0_r14, `auto_companies`.`locale` AS t0_r15, `auto_companies`.`visible` AS t0_r16, `auto_companies`.`created_at` AS t0_r17, `auto_companies`.`updated_at` AS t0_r18, `auto_companies`.`details` AS t0_r19, `auto_companies`.`logo` AS t0_r20, `auto_companies`.`cars_url` AS t0_r21, `auto_companies`.`other_lang_key` AS t0_r22, `auto_companies`.`is_featured` AS t0_r23, `auto_companies`.`enhance_page` AS t0_r24, `auto_companies`.`conversion_id` AS t0_r25, `auto_companies`.`phone_conversion_label` AS t0_r26, `auto_companies`.`email_conversion_label` AS t0_r27, `auto_companies`.`is_verified` AS t0_r28, `auto_companies`.`admin_user_id` AS t0_r29, `auto_companies`.`deleted_at` AS t0_r30, `auto_company_translations`.`id` AS t1_r0, `auto_company_translations`.`auto_company_id` AS t1_r1, `auto_company_translations`.`name` AS t1_r2, `auto_company_translations`.`locale` AS t1_r3, `auto_company_translations`.`physical_address` AS t1_r4, `auto_company_translations`.`details` AS t1_r5, `auto_company_translations`.`created_at` AS t1_r6, `auto_company_translations`.`updated_at` AS t1_r7 FROM `auto_companies` LEFT OUTER JOIN `auto_company_translations` ON `auto_company_translations`.`auto_company_id` = `auto_companies`.`id` auto_company_branches WHERE (`auto_companies`.deleted_at IS NULL) AND (auto_company_branches.country_id =1 and  id=3242)
```

Comment: Please, paste the error.

Comment: Could you share the error with us please?

Comment: update ....please check

Comment: do you find a solution ?

Comment: No Sir.........

Comment: try this `AutoCompany.joins(:auto_company_branches).where("auto_company_branches.country_id  = ? and auto_companies.id = ?',country_id,id)`

Comment: do you have multiple country id or id ?

Comment: try this one also `AutoCompany.includes(:auto_company_branches).where(id: id, auto_company_branches: {country_id: country_id} )`

Comment: please share your database schema for `AutoCompany` and `AutoCompanyBranches`

Comment: You have a TYPO :) for opening you used `"` and for closing the `where` you used single quote `'`

Comment: @HaseebAhmad updated my answer please check it

Answer (score 0):

Try below query

```
AutoCompany.joins(:auto_company_branches).where("auto_company_branches.country_id =? and id=?",country_id,id)
```

In your query, you missed to used joins, so used `joins(:auto_company_branches)` instead of `where(:auto_company_branches)`

Comment: what the difference between my and your query

Comment: @use you were not used `joins` in your query

Comment: @HaseebAhmad what is your mysql version ?

Comment: thats not an issue

Comment: AutoCompany.joins(:auto_company_branches).where("auto_company_branches.country_id =? and auto_company.id=?",1,3216)

Comment: @HaseebAhmad do you have multiple country id and id  ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168192/discussion-between-vishal-and-haseeb-ahmad).